# Delete <> symbol in the sentence

Tags: regex

I have following sentence:

```
Magermilch, Wasser, <H>Milchzucker</>, Paniermehl 9%;
```

I am searching a regex for replace `<*>` with space.

After replace, the sentence above should looks like:

```
Magermilch, Wasser, Milchzucker, Paniermehl 9%;
```

Comment: [`<[^>]*>`](https://regex101.com/r/Hb2Bu5/2/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following regex: <.> I dont know what Programming languague ur using but in Java you should use:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<.>"); // or Pattern.compile("[<.>]")
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @zero_coding: It works only with a single character.

Comment: @Gurman gave the answer for multiple characters: <[^>]*>